# Safely read write a .txt file from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, filestream

I am using a .txt file to log exceptions thrown from various methods in my asp.net (4.0) project. I have a page which reads texts from that file on every 10 minutes. If there are Read and Write attempts at the same time, will it throw any exception? If you have any better technique to handle such problem, please let me know. Currently, i'm using the following code-

Writing to the file

```
using (StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(LogFilePath, true))
{
    Writer.WriteLine(ErrorMsg);
}
```

Reading from the file

```
using (FileStream fs=File.OpenRead(LogFilePath))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
           Response.Write(line + "</br>");
        }
    }
}
```

Is these approaches are safe?

Thank you.

Comment: No. Use `log4net` for example.

Answer (score 0):

As people already suggested, the simplest way is to use external libraries, which handle locking of the file.

However, if you still want to use your own code to do that, make sure you're synchronizing access to the file, using lock:

```
lock(lockObj)
{
    using (StreamWriter Writer = new StreamWriter(LogFilePath, true))
    {
        Writer.WriteLine(ErrorMsg);
    }
}
```

where lockObj is

```
static object lockObj = new object();
```